# Where is offline JavaScript form data on chrome and Firefox stored?

Tags: javascript

I ran a client-side script offline that involves processing form data. When I closed the window on chrome and Firefox, I was able to open the window through the history tab , but the forms were still filled out even though the windows were closed. Where is this data being stored?

how do I ensure form data is completely erased?

Comment: It's likely in your browser's profile folder somewhere - reset it completely if you want to make absolutely sure.

Comment: Or browse in InCognito mode, then it shouldn't save data.

Comment: You probably can't do anything in Javascript to clear this.